# Python telnetlib auto response prompt

Tags: python, huawei-mobile-services

I have some problem with python telnet lib, our network device didn't have "terminal length 0 / no more" etc.. so telnet read_until/read all not work every prompt appear and this prompt repeatedly appear until the end command output (about 10-20x press the space keyword) , and bring the python app hang,

i need advice about how to capture "---more--" and telnet lib press space/enter keyword automatically, is posible? i have successed to telnet/ssh many network device with my python code, exept this network device,

thank you

```
import telnetlib

user = b'user'
password = b'user'

tn = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.0.1',port=23)
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user + b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(password + b"\n")
tn.write(b"enable \n")
tn.write(password + b"\n")
tn.write(b"display current-configuration \n")
<<< here code i need advice >>>>

network device output : '--More--'

<<< or here code i need advice >>>>

tn.write(b'exit\n')
output = tn.read_until(b'exit')
print(output)
```